# Payment Integration Using Telr

Tags: ios, telr

I am currently working on Telr Gateway. I have downloaded the Swift 4.2 version Telr SDK and checked the sample test.

My question is: Should I send XML Request or directly I can send like which is mentioned in sample?

Comment: Guys., anyone please help me in Telr Payment Gateway.imported frameworks related to telr in sample file its working fine., the same while importing into project which contains Workspace, its not working . I checked in TelrSDK module there is no code copied.., If anyone having idea about this, please help me..

Comment: Hi as you have mentioned you moved to an  API integration procedure , I am also following the same, but facing an error of "Invalid request". As I have added question here , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841493/code01-code-messageinvalid-request-message-in-telr-payment-gateway-in-io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Drag and drop the `TelrSDK.framework` into Frameworks group.
2. Then go to your project's Target and add Telr framework in Embedded frameworks   and Linked frameworks.
3. Now clean and build the project.

Sample Payment Request.

Import the `TelrSDK` Framework. Then create a payment request object and assign the request to telrController's paymentRequest property. Then push or present the telr view controller. After entering the card details, you'll get the response in the view controller with StoryboardID called `ResultController` which inherits the `TelrResponseController`.

```
private func openTelrPaymentGateway() {
    paymentRequest = preparePaymentRequest()
    let telrVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TelrController") as! TelrController
    telrVC.title = "Telr"
    telrVC.paymentRequest = paymentRequest!
    navigationController?.pushViewController(telrVC, animated: true)
}

private func preparePaymentRequest() -> PaymentRequest{

    let paymentReq = PaymentRequest()
    paymentReq.key = "YOUR KEY"
    paymentReq.store = "YOUR STORE ID"
    paymentReq.appId = "123456789"
    paymentReq.appName = "YOUR APP NAME"
    paymentReq.appUser = "123456"
    paymentReq.appVersion = "0.0.1"
    paymentReq.transTest = "1"
    paymentReq.transType = "auth"
    paymentReq.transClass = "paypage"
    paymentReq.transCartid = String(arc4random())
    paymentReq.transDesc = "Test API"
    paymentReq.transCurrency = "AED"
    paymentReq.transAmount = "\(totalAmount)"
    paymentReq.transLanguage = "en"
    paymentReq.billingEmail = EMAIL
    paymentReq.billingFName = "Hany"
    paymentReq.billingLName = "Sakr"
    paymentReq.billingTitle = "Mr"
    paymentReq.city = "Dubai"
    paymentReq.country = "AE"
    paymentReq.region = "Dubai"
    paymentReq.address = "line 1"
    paymentReq.billingPhone="8785643"
    return paymentReq

}
```

Once the request is processed, you'll get the response from `TelrResponseController` class.

```
class PaymentGatewayVC: TelrResponseController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      print(message!)
      print(trace!)
      print(status!)
      print(avs!)
      print(code!)
      print(ca_valid!)
      print(cardCode!)
      print(cardLast4!)
      print(cvv!)
      print(tranRef!)

    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Vinoth., I tried this procedure first but TelrSDK class code not copied properly.,so I moved to API integration procedure and worked successfully.. anyway I will try your procedure once again.. Thanks Much for update..

Comment: If would be helpful for others if you guyz give sample. I am also working on TELR SDK  SWIFT but i did't find any way to add card details in request.